# Can a Roth 401(k) be transferred somehow to a Roth IRA if younger than 59.5-year-old and not leaving one's job?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, roth-ira, roth-conversion

I understand that:

- A Roth 401(k) may be rolled over to a Roth IRA if older than 59.5-year-old or if leaving one's job.
- It is possible to do in-service distributions from an after-tax 401(k) to a Roth IRA  or Roth  401(k) when employed, [if the employer's retirement plan allows it](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/86846/5656).

Can a Roth 401(k) be rolled over / in-service distributed / transferred somehow to a Roth IRA if  younger than 59.5-year-old and not leaving one's job?

Comment: Similar: [Does an in-service rollover of a Roth 401(k) to an existing 15 year old Roth IRA incur any tax?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/119644/14319). As in the comments, it depends if your employer's retirement plan allows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no legal restrictions that keep you from rolling any amount over, and there are no tax consequences.

The question is only if the employer's plan allows it. That  - obviously - depends on the specific employer's plans details. Some allow it and some not.